# How should I update variable `w` to `y` after computing 'y=w*x' in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I began to learn the Tensorflow for a few days ago. So this may be a silly question.

I wrote the following program which just compute`y=w*x` and , after that, update variable `w` to `y`. In this program, to update variable, I've used `update_w_op = tf.assign(w, y)` and call `update_w_op` operation like `sess.run(update_w_op)`. But with no luck, an error occurred. How should I modify my program?

Moreover, it would be a great if there is a way which update variable `w` just by calling `y`. Is there any way to do this?

Program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# My graph
w = tf.Variable(1)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
y = w*x

# Define operation for updating variable 'w'
update_w_op = tf.assign(w, y)

# Define variable initializer
initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initializer)
    # check w and y
    print("w:", sess.run(w))
    print("y:", sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:2}))
    # update
    sess.run(update_w_op)    # <--- An error occurred here.
    print("w:", sess.run(w)) # Here I expect `sess.run(w)` returns '2'.
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1349     try:
-> 1350       return fn(*args)
   1351     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1328                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1329                                    status, run_metadata)
   1330 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_112' with dtype int32
     [[Node: Placeholder_112 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-bb38863a68ac> in <module>()
     19     print("y:", sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:2}))
     20     # update
---> 21     sess.run(update_w_op)    # <--- An error occurred here.
     22     print("w:", sess.run(w)) # Here I expect `sess.run(w)` returns '2'.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1127       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1128                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1129     else:
   1130       results = []

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1342     if handle is None:
   1343       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1344                            options, run_metadata)
   1345     else:
   1346       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1361         except KeyError:
   1362           pass
-> 1363       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1364 
   1365   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_112' with dtype int32
     [[Node: Placeholder_112 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder_112', defined at:
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 125, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 356, in start
    self.shell.mainloop()
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 480, in mainloop
    self.interact()
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 471, in interact
    self.run_cell(code, store_history=True)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2856, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-131-cda6375ef3e5>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('paste', '')
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2095, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-27>", line 2, in paste
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/magics.py", line 199, in paste
    self.store_or_execute(block, name)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/magics.py", line 57, in store_or_execute
    self.shell.run_cell(b)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-131-bb38863a68ac>", line 5, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1680, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3141, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/kei/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_112' with dtype int32
     [[Node: Placeholder_112 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the `update_w_op` operation, you need to provide a value for the `x` placeholder. Just fix one line of code:

```
sess.run(update_w_op, feed_dict={x:2})
```